Getting rid of bad prarabdha karmas?
Prarabdha karmas mostly we have to endure in our present lifetime. But as Sri Ramakrishna paramahamsa claimed chanting gods name can lessen its intensity. So if I am destined to get a horrific death will I be able to avoid the horrific death and get a normal or even an honourable death? Please comment on this.

As per my reading, a deity or spiritually advanced person has ability to reduce effect but not remove it. Based on all references in this channel, name of God is safest way for spiritual growth. I believe Deity will give strength/ guidance to overcome.

Perhaps. Only the Lord knows how much, there is no way to know how much or how little.

If you desire you can change prabdha(here, situation of death) from naam japa
